# How do I get superagent-hawk to work with supertest

Tags: supertest, superagent

I have an API that I am trying to test. It uses hawk authentication. I have successfully test failure codes using supertest, but I'm not sure how to include the hawk authentication within test script.  I have found and installed superagent-hawk, which states it does work with supertest. Unfortunately, I am fairly new to all this and am unsure how to set it up.

Here's what I have (test.js):

```
var should = require('should');
var superTest = require('supertest')('mywebsite:3000/');
var addHawk = require('superagent-hawk');
var request = addHawk(superTest);

describe('controlllers', function() {
  describe('preregControllers', function() {
    describe('GET /mypage', function() {
      it('should be response code 200', function(done) {
        var creds = {
          "id": "testUser",
          "key": "testPass",
          "algorithm": "sha256"
        }
        request
          .get('mypage')
          .hawk(creds)
          .set('Accept', 'applications/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

When I try to run `mocha test.js`, I get the following:

```
mocha test.js 
~/Projects/myproject/node_modules/superagent-hawk/index.js:9
                      : superagent.Request.prototype;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (~/Projects/myproject/node_modules/superagent-hawk/index.js:9:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/Projects/myproject/test/api/controllers/test.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:468:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3
```

I've also tried:

`var request = require('supertest', 'superagent-hawk')('mywebsite:3000/');`

but that gave me the following, which was not unexpected:

`TypeError: request.get(...).hawk is not a function`

My working code looks like the following:

```
var should = require('should');
var response = require('supertest')('mywebsite:3000/');

describe('controlllers', function() {
  describe('preregControllers', function() {
    describe('GET /mypage', function() {
      it('should be response code 401', function(done) {
        request
          .get('mypage')
          .set('Accept', 'applications/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(401,{"category":"AUTHORIZATION","context":"Validating user credentials","message":"Unauthorized"})
          .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I also tried to tag this superagent-hawk, but I don't have the rep high enough to create a new tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, partially by looking at superagent-hawk's own tests/hawk.js file, and by playing around.  Here's how I did it:

```
var should = require('should');
var addHawk = require('superagent-hawk');
var superTest = addHawk(require('supertest'));
var request = superTest('mywebsite:3000/');

describe('controlllers', function() {
  describe('preregControllers', function() {
    describe('GET /mypage', function() {
      it('should be response code 200', function(done) {
        var creds = {
          "id": "testUser",
          "key": "testPass",
          "algorithm": "sha256"
        }
        request
          .get('mypage')
          .hawk(creds)
          .set('Accept', 'applications/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```